# Nuxt.js After npm run generate cannot find files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I’m trying to generate my app with npm run generate
on terminal. I’m not getting some error there is everything well generated. And in my development server everything work well routings components etc., but after generate when I open to index.html in dist folder I can’t access other pages, there are errors like that on chrome console.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
f8ff67c7350097487a5e.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
e63cddd635f290d15a6f.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
9a1a3c7742fdcce5403a.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
1e056384fb18617ca6a5.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
bde8656.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I try to upload dist folder to my ftp but there is too same…

here is my nuxt.config file

```
const pkg = require('./package')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc:https://github.com/nuxt-community/modules/tree/master/packages/bulma
    '@nuxtjs/bulma',
    // ['nuxt-validate', {
    //   lang: 'tr',
    //   // regular vee-validate options 
    // }]
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    postcss: {
      preset: {
        features: {
          customProperties: false
        }
      }
    },
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does your project load data from a server?.

Comment: No. there is just one api call have which i make something with response thats all.

Comment: How do u open your generated project? If you open your html file directly in browser it wont work. You need a http server

Comment: @Aldarund i have upload content of dist folder to my ftp and there is too not working, I think problem is browser search _nuxt folder outside of root

Comment: Do u upload and access it via root domain e.g yourdomain.com ? or yourdomain.com/somedir ?

Comment: @Aldarund yes i try to Access via yourdomain.com/dir/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you access it not via domain root you need to set it in nuxt config
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base

```
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/app/'
  }
}
```